# Cannot install Deduplication role on Windows Server 2019 0x80073701

Tags: windows, windows-server, windows-server-2019, deduplication, roles

I want to install the Deduplication role on Windows Server 2019 but I always get an  0x80073701 Error. I tried all sfc and Dism, updates but there where no problems, I also reinstalled update kb5011551 because it was noticeable in the CBS log. I dont know what I can try next, and I realy dont want to reinstall, doese someone here knows what I can try next?

Here is the CBS log, maybe someone can give me a hint on what I can look for.

```
2022-04-02 20:19:09, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log to WER report.
2022-04-02 20:19:09, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20220402181232.log to WER report.
2022-04-02 20:19:09, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20220402174426.log to WER report.
2022-04-02 20:19:09, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20220402152727.log to WER report.
2022-04-02 20:19:09, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20220402131309.log to WER report.
2022-04-02 20:19:09, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20220401152741.cab to WER report.
2022-04-02 20:19:09, Info                  CBS    Not able to add pending.xml to Windows Error Report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2022-04-02 20:19:09, Info                  CBS    Not able to add pending.xml.bad to Windows Error Report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2022-04-02 20:19:09, Info                  CBS    Not able to add SCM.EVM to Windows Error Report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2022-04-02 20:19:09, Error                 CSI    00000009 (F) STATUS_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING #36158# from CCSDirectTransaction::OperateEnding at index 0 of 1 operations, disposition 2[gle=0xd015000c]
2022-04-02 20:19:09, Error                 CSI    0000000a (F) HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING) #36000# from Windows::ServicingAPI::CCSITransaction::ICSITransaction_PinDeployment(Flags = 0, a = 9906cb8d8133065945b7e5d85177b14a, version 10.0.17763.1075, arch amd64, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, cb = (null), s = (null), rid = 'Package_2882_for_KB4592440~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.6.4592440-4992_neutral', rah = (null), manpath = (null), catpath = (null), ed = 0, disp = 0)[gle=0x80073701]
2022-04-02 20:19:09, Info                  CBS    Failed to pin deployment while resolving Update: Package_2882_for_KB4592440~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.6.4592440-4992_neutral from file: (null) [HRESULT = 0x80073701 - ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING]
2022-04-02 20:19:09, Info                  CBS    Failed to bulk stage deployment manifest and pin deployment for package:Package_1724_for_KB5011551~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.6 [HRESULT = 0x80073701 - ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING]
2022-04-02 20:19:09, Info                  CBS    CommitPackagesState: Started persisting state of packages
2022-04-02 20:19:09, Info                  CBS    CommitPackagesState: Completed persisting state of packages
2022-04-02 20:19:09, Info                  CSI    0000000b@2022/4/2:18:19:09.408 CSI Transaction @0x15bac4d7340 destroyed
2022-04-02 20:19:09, Info                  CBS    Perf: Resolve chain complete.
2022-04-02 20:19:09, Info                  CBS    Failed to resolve execution chain. [HRESULT = 0x80073701 - ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING]
2022-04-02 20:19:09, Error                 CBS    Failed to process single phase execution. [HRESULT = 0x80073701 - ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING]
2022-04-02 20:19:09, Info                  CBS    WER: Generating failure report for package: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.17763.1, status: 0x80073701, failure source: Resolve, start state: Installed, target state: Installed, client id: DISM Package Manager Provider
2022-04-02 20:19:09, Info                  CBS    Not able to query DisableWerReporting flag.  Assuming not set... [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2022-04-02 20:19:09, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log to WER report.
2022-04-02 20:19:09, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20220402181232.log to WER report.
2022-04-02 20:19:09, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20220402174426.log to WER report.
2022-04-02 20:19:09, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20220402152727.log to WER report.
2022-04-02 20:19:09, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20220402131309.log to WER report.
2022-04-02 20:19:09, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20220401152741.cab to WER report.
2022-04-02 20:19:09, Info                  CBS    Not able to add %windir%\winsxs\pending.xml to WER report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2022-04-02 20:19:09, Info                  CBS    Not able to add %windir%\winsxs\pending.xml.bad to WER report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2022-04-02 20:19:10, Info                  CBS    Reboot mark cleared
2022-04-02 20:19:10, Info                  CBS    Winlogon: Simplifying Winlogon CreateSession notifications
2022-04-02 20:19:10, Info                  CBS    Winlogon: Deregistering for CreateSession notifications
2022-04-02 20:19:10, Info                  CBS    FinalCommitPackagesState: Started persisting state of packages
2022-04-02 20:19:10, Info                  CBS    FinalCommitPackagesState: Completed persisting state of packages
2022-04-02 20:19:10, Info                  CBS    Enabling LKG boot option
2022-04-02 20:19:10, Info                  CBS    Exec: Will not run corruption repair because no store corruption found.
2022-04-02 20:19:10, Info                  CBS    Exec: Processing complete.  Session: 30951102_618499846, Package: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.17763.1, Identifier: Windows Foundation [HRESULT = 0x80073701 - ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING]
2022-04-02 20:19:11, Error                 CBS    Failed to perform operation.  [HRESULT = 0x80073701 - ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING]
2022-04-02 20:19:11, Info                  CBS    Session: 30951102_618499846 finalized. Reboot required: no [HRESULT = 0x80073701 - ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING]
2022-04-02 20:19:11, Info                  CBS    Failed to FinalizeEx using worker session [HRESULT = 0x80073701]
```

Comment: I notice the problem is with [KB4592440](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/december-8-2020-kb4592440-os-build-17763-1637-expired-9181daf2-e180-b711-162f-b0d1a8d38dd9) which has been retired. Have you fully updated Windows Server?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate what the current build of Windows Server 2019 you have installed. You should avoid kb5011551 since it was released more than a year ago it's long been replaced by a newer patch

Comment: I have fully updated the server over the update utility. The current build is 1809, and I'm using the Standard Evaluation Version of Windows Server 2019.